# Overcome arm gcc bug with -fPIC and -Os

Tags: gcc, arm, compiler-optimization

There seems to be a bug with new gcc-arm versions, as described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1927055) and as seen in [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/rYxTPdTcd).

The issue is that gcc generates redundant code, which is obviously not minimal in size as requested (-Os). gcc 4.5.4 generates better code (shorter in size, without redundant stack frame).

Is there any workaround for this issue? Maybe another compiler flag? I searched gcc flags and couldn't find something.

Comment: FWIW, _ARM gcc trunk (linux)_ generates the same code as 4.5.4 (at least after adding the `-marm` option).

Comment: use `-O2`, that would give same result https://godbolt.org/z/jhWP3vjjn. And personally, compare compiler output by a single one line function is questionable practice

Comment: @user3124812 I need the code to be as small as possible (this is a part of a much bigger project), so I must use `-Os`.

Comment: @Michael What exactly is ARM gcc trunk? I want to be able to use gcc latest features without the described issue. In compiler explorer it isn't clear what version it is.

Comment: @RalphMimms Adding the `-v` option gives `gcc version 11.0.1 20210315 (experimental) (GCC)`.

Comment: dont always assume that optimize for size produces the smallest binary.  often yes but sometimes not...using position independent code adds code, you have to ask yourself do I really need to bloat the code with fpic, can I live without it?

Comment: @old_timer What you describe (optimize for size doesn't produce the smallest binary) sounds like a bug, anyway the added code as can bee seen in compiler explorer makes no sense, and as far as I can see, has nothing to do with PIC. Unfortunately, I can't live without the code being position independent, nor can I live with the code being bigger than it was before. The development is for an embedded controller, and the wanted code is for a stub which is limited in size which get loaded to a malloced address, so it has to be PIC.

Comment: I have seen it happen and I cant see it as a bug, it is not like the compiler is going go through every combination of optimizations for ever file and link to completion to find the smallest binary.  It is going to tune optimizations for size and hope for the best.  I have seen -O3 build smaller on -Os on some compilers for some code.  it is not unexpected...as a result, worth trying from time to time just to see what you get...

Comment: should never use malloc in an embedded controller.   unless this is on top of an RTOS, but even there....point being that you are fighting yourself by using optimize for size and PIC at the same time...here again just for fun build for size but without pic.  also use the flto stuff to remove all the functions and items that are not actually being used...

Comment: which arm core is this?